# Django: How to limit model list access permission to its owner?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have a django model and and i want that model to be accessed only by its owner(user who created the model). So i created a permission class as follows

```
class IsOwnerOnly(permissions.BasePermission):


def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

    # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
    return obj.owner == request.user
```

and applied this permission on modelviewset

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

While accessing a single item it works, But even then every authenticated user can access the list of items. So how could i limit the item access to only its owner?

I have included Tokenauthentication in  settings page as shown

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

),
}
```

and the item looks like

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `return obj.owner == request.user`,is `owner`  a field to model `Item`?and you can't control who can access item list by owner,if you what,you need to override `has_permission` to class `IsOwnerOnly`

Comment: yup. it is a field

Comment: i have included it now. pls check

Answer (score 2):

You can override the method `get_queryset` on your View

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

This way the method `list` (from ModelViewSet) will call your "get_queryset" to build the pagination with the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control who can access item list by owner,if you what,you need to override has_permission to class IsOwnerOnly, like:

```
class IsAuthenticatedOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # work when your access /item/
        if request.user and is_authenticated(request.user):
            if request.user.id in [1, 2, 3]:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # work when your access /item/item_id/
        # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

Notice:`has_permission` work when your access `/item/`(list),`has_object_permission` work when your access `/item/item_id/`(retrieve and update).

If you want to let user see the items only he created,simple as:

```
class ItemsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Items.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemsSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Comment: ok. but what i need is to limit permission only to its owners

Comment: i can do that on accessing /item/item_id/ but not on accessing /item/

Comment: your want your user can only see the items he create?

Comment: ya. that is what i want